# Debugging Caesar cipher in Python

Tags: python, encryption

When I type "Hello World!" it gets encrypted to "KNUUXWZXAUMX" If I put that into my decryption code the decryption comes back as "HKRRUTWUXRJU".

Since this is a high school project there are some required functions needed etc. I have to use functions, lists, and loops for my code. There are other requirements I'm supposed to later on like including upper case letters, digits, and punctuation to be encrypted.

My code is:

```
text = (input('Add some text: '))
def toList(text):
    text.split()
    return text

def encrypt(text):
    shift = 3
    text1 = text
    encryption = ""
    for x in text1:
        xCode = ord(x)
        xGuide = xCode - ord("A")
        newGuide = (xGuide + shift) % 26
        newCode = newGuide + ord("A")
        newLetters = chr(newCode)
        encryption = encryption + newLetters
    print("encrypted text: ", encryption)
    print("text:", text1)

encrypt(text) 
cipherText = (input('Add some encrypted text: '))

def decrypt(cipherText):
    shift = 3
    cipherText1 = cipherText
    regularText = ""
    for x in cipherText1:
        xCode = ord(x)
        xGuide = xCode - ord("A")
        newGuide = (xGuide - shift) % 26
        newCode = newGuide + ord("A")
        newLetters = chr(newCode)
        regularText = regularText + newLetters

    print("Encrypted text:", cipherText1)
    print("Decrypted text:", regularText)

decrypt(cipherText)
```

Comment: what happens when you try with a text that's all caps?

Comment: AFAIK, there are many related questions on stack overflow. Perhaps the answers to those questions will provide helpful clues to you.

Comment: Please, get your indentation right. Use spaces for indentation.

Comment: FYI: there is [CodeReiew.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask review of your code with requirements...

Comment: @kelalaka: CodeReview IMHO requires code that works. This code does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I'm glad you ask "how to debug this" and not "how to fix this".

The initial observation or bug report was to type `Hello World!`, which gets encrypted to `KNUUXWZXAUMX`, but the same text is decrypted as `HKRRUTWUXRJU`.

You could use a debugger now and step through your code, but you can be smarter in various ways.

**Step 1**: Set up version control and make sure you have commited all your work so you can roll back any time you like. Ideally create a bug fix branch.

**Step 2**: make the problem reproducible without user input. Instead of

```
text = (input('Add some text: '))
```

write

```
text = "Hello World!"
```

and instead of

```
cipherText = (input('Add some encrypted text: '))
```

write

```
cipherText = "KNUUXWZXAUMX"
```

Doing so will save you a lot of time and prevent you from typos in the input. Stage to version control or commit if you're on a branch.

This would be a great stage at which to ask Stack Overflow, BTW. Do not let the guys on SO input themselves. They might make mistakes.

**Step 3**: reduce the data.

Using `"A"` as input gives `"D"` as encrypted text - which looks good!

Using `"a"` as input gives `"J"` as encrypted text - so you found an input with much less characters to reproduce the issue. It will be much easier to debug a single character instead of a sentence.

At this point, you have already eliminated 50% of your code for debugging: you know that at least one problem seems to be in the `encrypt` function, not in the `decrypt` function. (There might still be more issues, though).

**Step 4**: Debug.

Put a breakpoint early into the `encrypt` function and step through your code. Check every intermediate result and think about it.

You don't know what a debugger is? Download PyCharm Community Edition and read about its debugger. You need to know how to use a debugger. It's an indispensable tool

Comment: What's wrong in the code? This is left as an exercise for the reader and for OP.

Comment: I like this answer. Debugging seems to be a vanishing skill among the current generation of computer science students.

Comment: _Technically_, OP didn't ask a question at all :) Useful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: indeed, there is no question mark anywhere. I hope I didn't remove it with my edit. Let me check ...

Comment: Wow, thank you for all the help! But my code still does not seem to work... I can't use step 2 since I am required to use user input... I tried debugging on the program I'm using for school called "replit" but I didn't seem to get anywhere. For step 3 would you like me to change    
* xGuide = xCode - ord("A")    newCode = newGuide + ord("A") *                                   
to * xGuide = xCode - ord("A") newCode = newGuide + ord("a") * or am I misunderstanding... Sorry about this

Comment: @iraxks: you only use step 2 as long as your code does not work. As soon as it works, you change it back to unser input. Do not use a REPL - they typically do not have debuggers. But yeah, I know, schools may require you to use tools that professionals would not use. It's so sad. A lot of teachers don't know how to use a debugger, too.

Comment: @iraxks: for step 3, it's not so simple unfortunately. I understand that you might want to include special characters in the end. But at the same time, it's very likely that your results shall exclude characters that are not printable. Therefore you need a definition of an alphabet like `alphabet = "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"` which later includes special characters. You would then find the index in the alphabet, add the offset, then modulo that against the number of characters in the alphabet and pick the character at that index of the alphabet.